# java source code class

Tags: java, class

Can anyone help to advise what I am doing wrong. I am trying to search a class for objects by year but if there are no matches I want a statement to print out that there are no matches but its not working it just is printing out even if the year is found. Thanks in advance for help

```
   //search by year 

    public void searchByYear(int year){
        for(Book s : books){
            if(s.getYear()==year){
                System.out.println(s.toString());
            }
        }System.out.println("No match");
    }
```

Comment: You need to record whether there was any matches e.g. in a `boolean` variable and if there wasn't, print out no matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `noneMatch`() from Java8 Streams and do this as follows:

```
if(list.stream().map(Book::getYear).noneMatch(( matchyear -> matchyear == year))) {
  System.out.println("No match");
}
```

**Without Java8:**

```
boolean isFound = false;
for(Book s : books){
    if(s.getYear()==year){
      isFound = true;
    }
}
if(!isFound) {
   System.out.println("No match");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public void searchByYear(int year){
    boolean foundAny = false;
    for(Book s : books){
        if(s.getYear()==year){
            foundAny = true;
            System.out.println(s.toString());
        }
    }
    if (!foundAny) {
        System.out.println("No match");
    }
}
```

We use a boolean variable `foundAny` to track if a year was found. We print the "No match" only if it was not found.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution:

```
final List<Book> matches = new ArrayList<>();
for (Book s : books) {
    if (s.getYear() == year) {
        matches.add(s);
    }
}

if (matches.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("No match");
} else {
    for (Book s : matches) {
        System.out.println(s.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for replying :-) Great to learn some new things